# How can I run a specific migration in Symfony 5 for my mysql database?

Tags: migration, symfony5

Hi every body I'm learning Symfony 5, on migrations lessons, after a lot of `make:migration` commands, this time I've this message[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV2sU.png)

And on `doctrine:migrations:migrate` command, I've this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvFS5.png)

But in my migrations file , there's a migration with create `etudiant` table.
So I'll know how to run that one migration for having that table in my database, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error often happened when you got some differents between the last migration file and your BDD.

First of all your script seems to drop 'etudiant' table but this one does not exist. May be you have drop it before.
However you have many possibility :

- You can delete all migration file on your symfony project (under migrations folder), then delete all sql entry on `doctrine_migration_versions`.
  After that you can redo your migration command line (make:migration and doctrine:migrations:migrate).
- You can edit the last migration file on your symfony projet and delete the drop table in trouble.

Comment: Thanks kevin, I removed all migrations files and redid migration commands lines and all's away! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`doctrine:migrations:migrate` will execute all your available migrations.

If you are looking to execute a specific migration, just use:

```
doctrine:migrations:execute --up 'DoctrineMigrations\VersionXXXX'
```

And, if you want to remove it so you can run it again, you can do this:

```
doctrine:migrations:execute --down 'DoctrineMigrations\VersionXXXX'
```

You will find the command list here:
https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#usage